# Getting started with time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

With some great help from this forum, I have been able to get up and running with some basic time series analysis in R.  Right now, my needs are mostly univariate time series.

**Here is my question:**

I can read in daily data from database into a data frame.  I have two columns, date which is understood by R as POSIXct and the second which is the value of interest and numeric.  What is the best, most straightforward way to make this a ts object where R understands the start/end dates and represents daily observations dynamically?  It seems to me that I shouldn't be required to (when coercing my object to a ts object)  manually tell it the start and end dates when the data frame is already has it.

For some context, I have been able to aggregate other data from daily to weekly, but find myself doing things in ways that just seem long and unnecessary considering R already understands my raw data as time.  As you can tell, I am new to R and time series in R, but I figure that since R is so powerful, there probably is a pretty easy way around my issues.

Comment: You are familiar with the tutorial at http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/R_time_series_quick_fix.htm? Admittedly, it accompanies another package / book, but there may be some potential for carry over.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did see this and I think it is fantastic.  I did edit my question to just focus on how to read in a univariate time series.  Mainly, if I have the dates for my daily data, how can I construct a univariate time series in R dynamically?  I have tried a few methods but they seem to include the date as another variable when I would only like to use it as a reference for start/end dates.  Sorry, new to R and I am just trying to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you need the package xts.
Create your time serie using

```
install.packages('xts')
library(xts)
X = xts(coredata(DF[,2]), order.by=DF[,1])
```

Then you will be able to manipulate your data easily.

```
to.weekly(X)  
to.monthly(X)
```

Please note that you will then manipulate xts objects and not ts. But no worries, you can go back to ts whenever needed.